# Cannot create a Redshift materialized view that depends on another materialized view due to missing permissions

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have designed a schema for my data flow where one MV depends on another. When I run the `CREATE` statements as a superuser, everything works fine. However when I run them as *the owner of the database*, but not a superuser, I get the following error:

```
permission denied for relation mv_tbl__my_source_view__0
```

OK, that's some system table that Redshift creates. And sure enough, if I do `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser`, the `CREATE` statement passes. However, for that to work, I need to pause operations as *myuser* after creating the source view, then run the `GRANT` command from the *superuser*, then resume creating the dependent view. So in short, I can no longer run migrations from *myuser*.

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` doesn't seem to do anything; tried to do it `FOR USER rdsdb`, the system user - also no effect. Still need to explicitly `GRANT` after creating the first view.

I really don't want to run every future migration as the superuser, so looking for something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so first of all, the problem is NOT that the user is lacking privileges.  Giving it privileges does fix view creation (did it with a procedure), but then the source materialized view is not allowed to update, because

```
ERROR:  Update of materialized view my_dependent_view failed
DETAIL:  cannot drop table mv_tbl__my_source_view__0 because other objects depend on it
```

The actual problem is that the source view used `GROUP BY` but did not include the `GROUP BY` column in the `SELECT` clause. So to fix this error, **I added the GROUP BY column to the SELECT clause in the source view** - although the dependent view doesn't use it, seems like it is required for the views to function.